# SqlDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with `SqlDataReader`.

Here's my code. the problem is when I debug it it doesn't go further than

```
while(dr.read())
```

it means the value returned by `dr.Read()` is false. I don't know what's wrong.

```
    if (CS_time_date[i].Substring(0, 2) == "CS")
    {
        string cardserial = CS_time_date[i].Substring(4, 5);
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WindowsAppEmp.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Card_reg ", con);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if ((dr["Cardserial"].ToString() == cardserial))
                        {
                            flag = 1;
                            string EmpID = dr["Id"].ToString();
                            string F_Name = dr["fname"].ToString();
                            string L_Name = dr["lname"].ToString();
                            //   Insert_EmpReport(EmpID, F_Name, L_Name, cardserial, CS_time_date,con);
                            string strsql1 = "Insert into Emp_Report (EmpId,CS,fname,lname,CheckIn,CheckOut,Date,Status) values (@EmpID,@Cs,@fname,@lname,@CheckIn,@CheckOut,@Date,@Status)";
                            SqlCommand report_cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql1, con);
                            report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", EmpID);
                            report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cs", cardserial);
                            report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", F_Name);
                            report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", L_Name);
                            if (CS_time_date[i].Substring(9, 10) == "56")
                                if (CS_time_date[i + 2] == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"))
                                {
                                    report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckIn", CS_time_date[i + 1]);
                                    report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Present");
                                }

                                else
                                    report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Absent");

                            else
                                report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckOut", CS_time_date[i + 1]);

                            report_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", CS_time_date[i + 2]);


                        }
                        else
                            flag = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
} while (reader.Peek() != -1);

reader.Close();
```

Comment: Do you have any records in the `Card_reg` table?

Comment: You've provided far more code here than you really need to. Please cut it down to just the bits that are required to demonstrate the problem.  For example, you don't need anything more than some diagnostic logging within the `while` loop... Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: yes I have Card_reg table in my database file

Comment: You have `Card_reg` table in your database but does this table contain any records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the `Card_reg` table defined in your database but this table doesn't contain any values in it - it is empty. That's why the `select * from Card_reg` query doesn't return any results and the data reader has nothing to read.

Comment: consider re-implementing this as SELECT INTO.  You'll save a ton of time in network traffic (once you get some data into your tables of course!)